# How to copy a JSON config file when installing my package

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install

I am creating a custom npm package and i would like to add a JSON config file.

I would like to add this file in the root path of the node app when a `npm install mypackage` is done

I know it is possible as this is what typescript is doing, adding a tsconfig.json file in my app folder when I do `npm install typescript`

I guess it is a package.json config but I don't know which.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using genechk awnser :

I had to add a "postinstall" script to my package.json, but i also had to add "node" command before in order to execute the script :

```
"scripts" : [
  ...
  "postinstall" : "node scripts/postinstall.js"
  ]
```

Also i had to add the script to the delivered files from the package :

```
  "files": [
    ...
    "scripts/**/*"
  ]
```

Finlay my postinstall.js looks like this :

```
const fs = require('fs');

// __dirname is "{ProjectFolder}/node_modules/mypackage/config"

const CONFIG_SRC = `${__dirname}/../config/`;
const CONFIG_DEST = `${__dirname}/../../../`;

const CONFIG_MYPACKAGE = 'mypackageconfig.json';

fs.copyFile(`${CONFIG_SRC}/${CONFIG_MYPACKAGE}`, `${CONFIG_DEST}/${CONFIG_MYPACKAGE}`, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`File ${CONFIG_MYPACKAGE} copied`);
});
```

Also to be fully proper i had to use an uninstall.js script following the same logic and deleting the file

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `postinstall` script.

```
{ "scripts" :
  ...
  "postinstall" : "scripts/postinstall.js"
  }
}
```

Here’s the [explanation of npm lifecycle events](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples) in docs:

> For example, if your package.json contains this:
>
> ```
> { "scripts" :
>   { "install" : "scripts/install.js"
>   , "postinstall" : "scripts/install.js"
>   , "uninstall" : "scripts/uninstall.js"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> then **scripts/install.js** will be called for the install and post-install stages of the lifecycle, and **scripts/uninstall.js** will be called when the package is uninstalled. Since **scripts/install.js** is running for two different phases, it would be wise in this case to look at the **npm_lifecycle_event** environment variable.

Comment: Thanks very much. Si "install" "postinstall" and "uninstall" are reserved keywords in the "scripts" array, used by npm if found. I will truc this ;-)